# not able to render view in Tile2 with spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, tiles

I my project I am using tile for view technology. .

every thing seems Ok

when I send a request it reaches a Controller then controller return a view name It is

able to find it in template.xml but finally is not able to render on browser and shows error 404 not found

what can be the reason please tell me I have wasted 2 days in it.enter code here

template.xml is

```
    <definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/common/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="backLink" value="/accountprofile/homePage" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/common/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

<definition name="ok" extends="default">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/body2.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
```

and my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testing/data")
public ModelAndView account(ModelMap modal)
{
    System.out.println("incontroller");
    . 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    return new ModelAndView("ok");

}
```

And one more thing I am using maven for jar dependencey

Comment: You should log debug messages from *org.springframework.web* and have a look at what they tell you.

Comment: Use browser's developer tools to figure out which URL it is trying to access for which it gets 404.